# Two Models in Angular for Passing & Display Data

Tags: angular, angular6, ngxs, angular-state-managmement

I have a problem with using models in ngxs.
I have to use different model for passing data to api and getting data from the api

I have a Report model and NetIncome model basically. How will i able to integrate them since theres an error on my code. I can only use one model? Or how can i revise this in my model?

I just want the best practices on my Angular app so i want the proper models to be assigned. Feel free to restructure or change a lot of codes etc...

Here the stackblitz link [**Click Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/two-models-in-ngxs)

```
@Action(GetNetIncomes)
  GetNetIncomes(ctx: StateContext<ReportStateModel>, { payload }: GetNetIncomes) {
    return this.reportsService.getNetIncomes(payload).pipe(
      tap((result: NetIncome) => {
        ctx.patchState({
          net_incomes: result,
        });
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getNetIncomes returns an array of Reports or Report[] and then you are trying to cast it to a NetIncome when it will not comply.  I suggest adding a map operator before the tap to transform result into a NetIncome or change the type of a net_incomes in ReportStateModel

Comment: Sure thing, as discussed in chat we have a simple domain object misalignment.  Take a peek at this ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/two-models-in-ngxs-nmkp5h?file=src/app/store/report.state.ts